# rails joins and merge method in heroku postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am having an issue with joins and merge method when the app is deployed to heroku.

```
def self.get_gift_by_gender_age(c)
 result = self.where(:gender => [c.gender, "unisex"]).joins(:age_classifications).merge(AgeClassification.by_age_range(c))
end
```

This works fine in mysql but returns no results in postgres.  It also doesn't give me an error so I don't know how to trouble shoot it.

EDIT:

Below is the query generated:

```
SELECT "products".* FROM "products" INNER JOIN "age_classifications" ON "age_classifications"."product_id" = "products"."id" WHERE "products"."gender" IN ('Female', 'unisex') AND "age_classifications"."age_range_id" = 1
```

Comment: Have you tried run "$: heroku logs"? There should be some error there if something's wrong with the query. Also can you post the query generated by this? And just to be sure doublecheck that you have data you expect in production database on heroku.

Comment: Hi @MarekTakac, heroku logs shows absolutely nothing...it loaded the page fine with no error.  I did also check to make sure it is supposed to return one result.